# Referencing Sharepoint 2010 bin folder

Tags: sharepoint-2010, bin-folder

I have added a resource to my WebApplication's bin folder the following way:
http://girishm.blog.com/2010/10/19/how-to-add-assemblies-into-gac-web-applications-bin-folder-using-wsps-created-using-visual-studio-2010s-sharepoint-projects-2/

Now all I need to know is: how do I reference the resource in the bin folder from my code-behind in my sharepoint project? What is the relative path of the resource on the farm? It is not a css/js/image file. It is a custom file I need to reference by its path on the server, how do I do this?

Is there any other way to deploy custom resources to a sharepoint farm, which can then later be referenced by its path on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

right click your project -> add -> SharePoint Mapped Folder

Comment: If I put my resource in a mapped folder called BIN then how do I reference it? Is the path something like "_bin\resource.filetype" ?

Comment: for example, I've referenced images like this "~/_layouts/images/navigationWebpartVersion2/dropDwnArrow.PNG";